# Javascript array splice causing out of memory exception?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am basically trying to sort an input of numbers on the fly by inserting the numbers to the correct position (not 100% sure but this should be insertion sort). My understanding is that to insert into an array in javascript you need to use the array splice method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp .

My code in attempt of achieving my goal is as below:

```
var N = parseInt(readline());
var powers = [0];
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var pi = parseInt(readline());
    for(var j=i;j<powers.length; j++ ){
        if(powers[j]>pi){
            powers.splice(j,0,pi);
        }
        else if(j+1==powers.length){
            powers[j+1]=pi;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get an out of memory exception. I just want to understand is what I am doing wrong in the code above. If I am using the splice method wrong and it is the cause of the memory leak, what is actually happening under the hood?
I know there are other ways I could do this sorting but I am particularly interested in doing an insertion sort with javascript arrays.

Comment: Whatever environment you're using, there's bound to be a debugger available for it. For instance, all major web browsers have fully-featured debuggers built in. NodeJS has a few available, one of which is `node-inspector`. I suggest interrupting what you're doing and learning to use that debugger to step through code statement-by-statement, so you can see how the code is running. There's nothing more informative that watching exactly how your code runs.

Answer (score 3):

In your `else` condition, you're adding to the array, making it one longer. That means when the loop next checks `powers.length`, it will be a higher number, which means you'll go into the loop body again, which means you'll add to the array again, which means you'll go back into the loop body again, which means...you see where this is going. :-)

Once you've added the number to the array (regardless of which branch), exit the loop (for instance, with `break`).

---

Side note: You won't be doing a proper insertion sort if you start `j` at `i` as you are currently. `i` is just counting how many entries the user said they were going to enter, it's not part of the sort. Consider: What if I enter 8 and then 4? If you start `j` at `i`, you'll skip over 8 and put 4 in the wrong place. `j` needs to start at 0.

Comment: Also the `if` case makes the array longer. So it really happens in each iteration.

Comment: @trincot: Good point, it does, it's just that at least in that case we'll move on, since `powers[j] > pi` won't be true anymore. Still, good point.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the break. Fundamental error on my side.